# rails generate scaffold throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffold

When i run "**rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string**" throws below error, thank you in advance.

```
/Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/projects/ruby/rails_projects/demo_app/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for #<DemoApp::Application:0x007fc8e1507fb0> (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
```

my ruby environment is as shown below

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 451) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0
     - /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin
     - /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin
     - /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin
     - /Users/mithunraj.nanjegowda/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Can you share the content of `application.rb` in the question.

Comment: Also `/config/environments/development.rb`?